# How to get the respective group of names and weights for repeating sports...?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having 3 dictionaries....

```
dic1 = {
    'g1': ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'], 
    'g2': ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'], 
    'g3': ['gaurav', 'geeta']
}
dic2 = {
    'g1': ['hockey', 'basketball', 'football'], 
    'g2': ['cricket', 'chess', 'badminton', 'carrom'], 
    'g3': ['pool', 'hockey', 'tabletennis']
}
dic3 = {
    'g1': ['45', '35', '56'], 
    'g2': ['67', '76', '65', '50'], 
    'g3': ['8', '70', '96']
}
```

Here, 'hockey' is present in two groups and the weights are different...

Also some calculations of weights are to be done for group of names with respective weights only...

What I want is for a sport the respective weights should be extracted and calculations are to be performed for respective group names.

In these case:

```
For ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'], weight=45 
For ['gaurav', 'geeta'], weight=70
```

should be taken for calculations...

I have done this much so far...

```
for k2,v2 in dic2.items():
   if 'hockey' in v2:
       position = v2.index('hockey')
       for k3,v3 in dic3.items():
          if k2==k3:
             weight = v3[position]
             print(weight)
```

Desired output:

```
 [{'comp': ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'], 'weight': 45},
  {'comp': ['gaurav', 'geeta'], 'weight': 70}]
```

Can anyone help me with these....?

Comment: What is the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You have three dicts and the keys are same between the three. This is the main co-relation factor between the three. So, while iterating through one dict, you can use the same key to get values from other dictionaries. The co-relation between sports and weights are coming based on their relative position in the respective lists. This is achieved by getting the index of a value in one list and getting the value at the same position in the corresponding list.

Based on your inputs and your output expectation, Try the below code:

```
dic1 = {
    'g1': ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'],
    'g2': ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'],
    'g3': ['gaurav', 'geeta']
}
dic2 = {
    'g1': ['hockey', 'basketball', 'football'],
    'g2': ['cricket', 'chess', 'badminton', 'carrom'],
    'g3': ['pool', 'hockey', 'tabletennis']
}
dic3 = {
    'g1': ['45', '35', '56'],
    'g2': ['67', '76', '65', '50'],
    'g3': ['8', '70', '96']
}

for k, v in dic2.items():
    for i, l in enumerate(v):
        print("Group = %s" %(k))
        print("Name List = %s, Sport = %s Weight = %s" %(dic1[k], l, dic3[k][i]))
```

**Output:**

```
Group = g3
Name List = ['gaurav', 'geeta'], Sport = pool Weight = 8
Group = g3
Name List = ['gaurav', 'geeta'], Sport = hockey Weight = 70
Group = g3
Name List = ['gaurav', 'geeta'], Sport = tabletennis Weight = 96
Group = g2
Name List = ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'], Sport = cricket Weight = 67
Group = g2
Name List = ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'], Sport = chess Weight = 76
Group = g2
Name List = ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'], Sport = badminton Weight = 65
Group = g2
Name List = ['megha', 'varun', 'tarun'], Sport = carrom Weight = 50
Group = g1
Name List = ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth', 'juhi'], Sport = hockey Weight = 45
Group = g1
Name List = ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth', 'juhi'], Sport = basketball Weight = 35
Group = g1
Name List = ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth', 'juhi'], Sport = football Weight = 56
```